# How to find certain sized clusters of points

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry, computational-geometry

Given a list of points, I'd like to find all "clusters" of N points. My definition of cluster is loose and can be adjusted to whatever allows an easiest solution: it could be N points within a certain size circle or N points that are all within a distance of each other or something else that makes sense. Heuristics are acceptable.

Where N=2, and we're just looking for all point pairs that are close together, it's pretty easy to do ~efficiently with a k-d tree (e.g. recursively break the space into octants or something, where each area is a different branch on the tree and then for each point, compare it to other points with the same parent (if near the edge of an area, check up the appropriate number of levels as well)). I recognize that inductively with a solution for N=N', I can find solution for N=N'+1 by taking the intersections between different N' solutions, but that's super inefficient.

Anyone know a decent way to go about this?

Comment: That's a pretty hard problem in the general case. Check out [Cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) and [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)

Comment: For N=2, what should it do if you have one point alone on either side with a bunch of pairs in between. Should it not pair the 2 outer-most points, or should it split the pairs in the middle so the outer points have pairs, or something in between?

Comment: It should find every instance of two points being close enough, which allows a point to be part of arbitrarily many clusters. So, I'm not looking to just do k-means clustering or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You start by calculating the [Euclidean minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree), e.g [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) can do this.  From there the precise algorithm depends on your specific requirements, but it goes roughly like this: You sort the edges in that graph by length.  Then delete edges, starting with the longest one.  It's a singly connected graph, so with each deleted edge you split the graph into two sub-graphs.  Check each created sub-graph if it forms a cluster according to your conditions.  If not, continue deleting edges.